# How to track post and get form actions in Chrome?

Tags: html, debugging, google-chrome, post, get

I am debugging one script quitely hard to understand and need to track all the post and get requests, occured while visiting page in Google Chrome. Which plugin should I use?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: No, I was searching for standart tool in Google Chrome and I have just found it.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. Deleloper Tools - Network tab has done the job!